# How long should I work at temp assignment before listing on my resume?

Tags: resume

I was employed at a large pharmaceutical company for 25 years and let go due to site outsourcing overseas 3 years ago. The site has slowly closed off sections but has not entirely closed yet. Last month I was brought back to the site through a temp agency in a position that's estimated to last between 6 to 12 months. I was in a job completely out of the Pharma field the last 3 years when I agreed to go back. Being this is a temp job through an agency (high pay but no benefits, sick pay, holidays) I would like to start looking for a permanent job in the Pharma field again. Is it ok to list the job on my resume now or should I wait a few months before its ok to list it and begin actively applying to open positions elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely add it to your CV as your current job.

You can (and probably should) make a note on your CV that it's a contract if you want to, but it's a legitimate role and unless you have been fired or something inside a month it is still current experience in your chosen field.  If challenged by prospective employers about why you are looking for another job after such a short term, you can say that it's a contract/temp position and that you are looking for something with more stability.